# Need some help producing a search box which will ONLY search a specific list

Tags: list, search

I work at a university and manage student placements. We only have access to the 2010 version of SharePoint. All I want to do is have a list of placement providers and the locations and then have a simple search box that will only search the list of providers, so that staff can search to see if the placement provider they want to use is already approved by the university.

I've followed this video to a 't'

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIq5ida9NSE but

When I get to the stage of 'connecting' the box to the list, I don't have the 'Connections' option on the drop down menu.

Can anyone shed some light on why this is? Or provide me with an alternative solution (some code I can input, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Do you not have the Connections option, or is it just grayed out? If it's grayed out, it's possible you have another web part already pointing to it. Check to make sure the receiving list is not already connected to another list/Filter.

Answer (score 0):

1) When you use the OOTB search box in the top right while in a list, it searches just that list. And if it doesn't, on the search results screen there should be a dropdown next to the search box with options like "This List" and "This Site" which you can use to limit the scope of the search. So you might not need to add a new search web part at all.

2) You can write your own custom visual web part that searches a list using CAML queries. This would also let you use more complex filtering options if you wanted.